# How to Integrate QuickBooks Desktop Payments with Node.js in Our E-commerce Project?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, payment-gateway, payment, quickbooks

Need help integrating QuickBooks Desktop payments with Node.js for our e-commerce project. Unsure about connecting to QuickBooks Desktop, processing payments, and handling invoices. Successfully implemented QuickBooks Online, but Desktop seems different. Seeking guidance on connection and payment methods.

QuickBooks Desktop + Node.js + React.js integration help needed. Thanks!